# Data changing before it's used in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I have been trying to send an email for each expired ticket in the database. Snip of it looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; I < rows.length; ++i) {
    if (today > new Date(rows[i].end_date)) {
        (function(id) {
            db.exec('update tickets ' +
                    'set status="expired" ' +
                    'where ticket_id= ' + id + ';' +
                    'insert into changes ' +
                    'values(' + id + ',' +
                        '"system",' +
                        '"ticket expired",' +
                        '"' + (today.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
                        '/' + today.getUTCDate() +
                        '/' + today.getUTCFullYear() +
                    '");',
                    function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }

                        console.log(id);
                        sendAlert(id);
                    }
            );
        })(rows[i].ticket_id);
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried to use an anonymous function to keep the data in each call from changing but it still didn't work.

I don't know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the execution of this task is asynchronous. When you need to iterate over asynchronous calls, the operation sequence is not guaranteed.

Maybe you need some control flow library such [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [Promise](http://bluebirdjs.com). There has some methods to control these flows even in iterations.